# Google Cloud Router BGP configuration

Tags: google-cloud-router

I'm having trouble bringing up a BGP session with my GCP Cloud router and my on premise router.
This is on a partner Interconnect link.

I thought I have a pretty basic configuration

But the connection state just goes between active and OpenConfirm

I have a Ubiquiti Edge Router. Which I have tested BGP on before.

I can ping the GCP router peer IP but I can't tell if my BGP packets are being received by the GCP router.

see BGP config below

Anyone have any other config examples? (note IP address replaced with x's for privacy)

I cant seem to get much from the GCP router logs

Are any Firewalls rules needed to allow BGP?

Thanks in advance for the feedback.

set protocols bgp 65001 neighbor 169.254.xxx.x1 remote-as 16550

set protocols bgp 65001 neighbor 169.254.xxx.x1 soft-reconfiguration inbound

set protocols bgp 65001 network 10.30.30.0/24

set protocols bgp 65001 parameters router-id 169.254.xxx.x2

Answer (score 1):

If you have already confirmed that:

1. Check that your on-premises router has been configured with a BGP session to your Cloud Routers.
2. you have the correct neighbor IP address configured on your on-premises router.
3. Check that the local ASN configuration on your on-premises router are properly set.

Then try to enable multi-hop BGP on your Ubiquiti Edge Router router with two hops.

I recommend to visit this [link](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/interconnect/support/troubleshooting#partner)

Comment: Thank you! it was the multihop statement

Comment: set protocols bgp 65001 neighbor 169.254.xxx.xx ebgp-multihop 2

Comment: I'm happy to know the answer was useful, in order to help the community in the future, could you please accept or upvote the answer? Thanks